# Use tkinter to visualize A Star search algorithm

Tags: python, tkinter, a-star

I've written an A* search algorithm and want to use tkinter to graphically visualize the search (in real time) like in the picture below, just a simpler version without menus, numbers in cells, previously tried paths or diagonal pathing.

In other words, I just need to display a grid with 7 possible textures (start, finish, path, obstacle, open node, closed node, untried) which updates automatically when the underlying matrix is changed.

How would the outline, so to speak, or architecture of this look? I already have a 2x2 matrix containing values for each node status (start.. obstacle and so forth), how can I use tkinter to display this matrix each time it's changed?

[image: a]

So far, I got this:

```
def main():
    theMap = .. # initial map with start, finish and obstacles
    root = Tk()
    my_gui = CellGrid(root,n,m,40,theMap)
    root.mainloop()
class CellGrid(Canvas):
    def __init__(self,master, rowNumber, columnNumber, cellSize, theMap):
        Canvas.__init__(self, master, width = cellSize * columnNumber , height = cellSize * rowNumber)

        self.cellSize = cellSize

        self.grid = []
        for row in range(rowNumber):
            line = []
            for column in range(columnNumber):
                line.append(Cell(self, column, row, cellSize, theMap[row][column]))
            self.grid.append(line)

        print self.grid[0][0].value
        self.draw()


    def draw(self):
        for row in self.grid:
            for cell in row:
                cell.draw()

class Cell():
    START_COLOR = "green"
    FINISH_COLOR = "red"
    UNTRIED_COLOR = "white"
    CLOSED_COLOR = "gray"
    OPEN_COLOR = "blue"
    OBSTACLE_COLOR = "black"
    PATH_COLOR = "orange"

    def __init__(self, master, x, y, size, value):
        self.master = master
        self.abs = x
        self.ord = y
        self.size= size
        self.fill = "white"
        self.value = value

    def setValue(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def draw(self):
        """ order to the cell to draw its representation on the canvas """
        if self.master != None :
            if self.value == 0:
                self.fill = self.UNTRIED_COLOR
            elif self.value == 1:
                self.fill = self.OBSTACLE_COLOR
            elif self.value == 2:
                self.fill = self.START_COLOR
            elif self.value == 3:
                self.fill = self.FINISH_COLOR
            elif self.value == 4:
                self.fill = self.OPEN_COLOR
            elif self.value == 5:
                self.fill = self.CLOSED_COLOR
            elif self.value == 6:
                self.fill = self.PATH_COLOR

            xmin = self.abs * self.size
            xmax = xmin + self.size
            ymin = self.ord * self.size
            ymax = ymin + self.size

            self.master.create_rectangle(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, fill = self.fill, outline = "black")
```

The idea is to draw the initial map (theMap) which only contains start, finish and obstacle nodes. Then, as A* changes the node, it can call a method in CellGrid with a new value for the node, which then updates the value and draws the corresponding texture.

However I can't get that far. When I run the code above, I get nothing, just an empty Tk window. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code posted does not run.  It does (with 3.x), when it begins, for instance, with

```
from tkinter import *

def main():
    Map = [
            [2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [0, 1, 3, 0, 0],
            [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          ]
    root = Tk()
    my_gui = CellGrid(root, len(Map), len(Map[0]), 40, Map)
    root.mainloop()
```

and parentheses are added to the print statement.

```
    print(self.grid[0][0].value)  # harmless in 2.7
```

and ends with `main()`.  Using simple data is very helpful for development.

To answer your immediate question, making the canvas visible requires the addition of `self.pack` after Canvas initialization.  With that, the Map above is displayed as expected.

To answer your architecture question, I suggest a different approach. Define a custom Map class that has the list of lists that you currently call theMap, a Canvas, and **getitem** and **setitem** methods that take a tuple of indexes. Write your A* functions in terms of amap[(i,j)].  The **setitem** method would take care of setting both the array and canvas.

Python style note: all the color code above can be replaced with

```
colors = {
            0: 'white',    # untried
            1: 'black',    # obstacle
            2: 'green',    # start
            3: 'red',      # finish
            4: 'blue',     # open
            5: 'gray',     # closed
            6: 'orange',   # path
         }
```

followed by `fill=colors[self.value]` in the create_rectangle call.

Comment: Excellent answer. self.pack was missing for getting the canvas up and running. But now I face a different problem. Either I have to run A-Star and Tkinter in separated threads. If so, how do I update the Tkinter map when A-star runs? Option number 2 is to run only one thread, and have A-Star call a function which updates the GUI each time it makes a change, but I don't think the latter is possible, is it?

Comment: Why do you think not?  The problem that I see is that full-speed A* will run much too fast, so that you will need to slow it down.  For instance, write a function `astep` that does one search 'step', recoloring the map with `a_map[(m,n)] = colorcode` statements as needed.  Then add `root.after(delay, astep)`, where delay might be, say, 50 (milliseconds), both to the end of `astep` and just before root.mainloop. See my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32296814/retrieve-from-database-dynamically-to-tkinter-gui for an example.

Comment: OK. I made Tkinter and A-Star in each separate thread, with A-star updating the map and calling the GUI to update the rendering each time it makes a change. Because I need to display the current path being explored, it is necessary to update the whole map each time A-Star makes a change. But that makes the whole program damn slow; without Tkinter I can run through 10 "scenarios" in a second, and with it one "scenario" takes 20 seconds, meaning 200 times slower (to give you an impression).