# Sleep() stops threads

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to run a script that spawns a couple of threads using root.after(). The sleep() seems to lock up the script. It never sees the Flag being set by the second root.after().

```
from time import sleep
from tkinter import *

global Flag
Flag = False

def setTimer():
    global Flag

    while(Flag==False):
        sleep(.1)
    print('Flag set')
    return

def setFlag():
    global Flag

    Flag=True
    return

root=Tk()
print('Start')

root.after(1,setTimer())
root.after(100,setFlag())

print('Done')
```

Answer (score 3):

`after` does not start a new thread, it runs a method inside the event-loop of Tk. So your while-loop will always block the program.

If you use `after` the method must do only non-blocking operations, like checking a flag. If you have background processes, use real threads. But notice: you must not alter the GUI inside these threads!

```
import tkinter as tk
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread, Event

flag = Event()

def worker():
    while not flag.is_set():
        sleep(.1)
    print('Flag set')

def set_flag():
    flag.set()

root = tk.Tk()
print('Start')

Thread(target=worker).start()
root.after(100, set_flag)

print('Done')
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your example whether you actually need an OS thread or merely an asynchronous event-driven task.  Daniel answered for the former, so I will answer for the latter.  The key is to make a task 'sleep' be calling root.after instead of time.sleep. (Note that `global name` is only needed and should only be used in functions that rebind `name`.)

```
from tkinter import *

flag = False

def setTimer():
    if flag:
        print('Flag set')
    else:
        print('Flag not set')
        root.after(100, setTimer)

def setFlag():
    global flag
    print('Setting flag')
    flag=True

root=Tk()
print('Start')

root.after(1,setTimer)
root.after(300,setFlag)

root.mainloop()
```

This prints 'Flag not set' three times, at 1, 101, and 201 milliseconds, but at 301 milliseconds, prints 'Flag set' instead.  (The timings are not exact, but the ordering should be.)

```
Start
Flag not set
Flag not set
Flag not set
Setting flag
Flag set
```

The repeated-after trick is how one animates anything in tkinter, such as moving a widget around the screen, or periodically changing colors.